# Retrieve all parameters of specific function: How to automate

Tags: decryption, .net, automation, dnspy

I'm trying to reverse engineer.NET binary with dnspy. I have a decryption routine that is used to display useful strings. It takes one integer value as a parameter and uses it in the decryption process, I wrote a script to decrypt one string per value.

This routine is called many times. I want to retrieve all integer values passed to this function to decrypt all strings.

How to automate this process using python for example?

Comment: why not simply brute force for i in range(0,1,200,1): decrypte(i)

Comment: you could probably also script it in dnSpy, but not in python by C# (via C# interactive?)

Comment: @blabb Thanks for replying but these values are randomly hardcoded and if I pass a wrong value the decryption will fail.

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik Could you explain more!
I just want all references to this function to get all passed values.

Comment: brute force is by nature letting something fail intentionally and finding all those which does not fail

Comment: @Raafat I would need to check the capabilities of dnSpy scripting to provide more info

Comment: @blabb you know what, I think it's a great idea and less time consuming :D